# Android unit testing view model that receives flow

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I have a ViewModel that talks to a use case and gets a flow back i.e `Flow<MyResult>`. I want to unit test my ViewModel. I am new to using the flow. Need help pls. Here is the viewModel below -

```
class MyViewModel(private val handle: SavedStateHandle, private val useCase: MyUseCase) : ViewModel() {

        private val viewState = MyViewState()

        fun onOptionsSelected() =
            useCase.getListOfChocolates(MyAction.GetChocolateList).map {
                when (it) {
                    is MyResult.Loading -> viewState.copy(loading = true)
                    is MyResult.ChocolateList -> viewState.copy(loading = false, data = it.choclateList)
                    is MyResult.Error -> viewState.copy(loading = false, error = "Error")
                }
            }.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
```

MyViewState looks like this -

```
 data class MyViewState(
        val loading: Boolean = false,
        val data: List<ChocolateModel> = emptyList(),
        val error: String? = null
    )
```

The unit test looks like below. The assert fails always don't know what I am doing wrong there.

```
class MyViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")

    private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    @Mock
    private lateinit var useCase: MyUseCase

    @Mock
    private lateinit var handle: SavedStateHandle

    @Mock
    private lateinit var chocolateList: List<ChocolateModel>

    private lateinit var viewState: MyViewState


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
        viewState = MyViewState()
        myViewModel = MyViewModel(handle, useCase)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun onOptionsSelected() {
        runBlocking {
            val flow = flow {
                emit(MyResult.Loading)
                emit(MyResult.ChocolateList(chocolateList))
            }

            Mockito.`when`(useCase.getListOfChocolates(MyAction.GetChocolateList)).thenReturn(flow)
            myViewModel.onOptionsSelected().observeForever {}

            viewState.copy(loading = true)
            assertEquals(viewState.loading, true)

            viewState.copy(loading = false, data = chocolateList)
            assertEquals(viewState.data.isEmpty(), false)
            assertEquals(viewState.loading, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to test here? What is the precise scenario that needs tested? Start by describing the test in words.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I need to test that the Flow<MyResult> is received by the viewmodel from the use case and a view state is built on it and given to the observer

Comment: @Maria Which method does that work?

Comment: onOptionsSelected() in the viewmodel

Comment: Why did you need `asLiveData` from your Flow?  Can't the ViewModel consume Flow directly?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky My Fragment observes a livedata and therefore I need to do asLiveData for the flow in viewModel

Comment: What is the purpose of this assertion: `viewState.copy(loading = true)` `assertEquals(viewState.loading, true)`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The viewState.loading is set to false whenever there is a result or error. So the assertion checks if the viewState is loading before there is any result or error

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are few issues in this testing environment as:

1. The `flow` builder will emit the result instantly so always the last value will be received.
2. The `viewState` holder has no link with our mocks hence is useless.
3. To test the actual flow with multiple values, delay and fast-forward control is required.
4. The response values need to be collected for assertion

Solution:

1. Use `delay` to process both values in the flow builder
2. Remove `viewState`.
3. Use `MainCoroutineScopeRule` to control the execution flow with delay
4. To collect observer values for assertion, use `ArgumentCaptor`.

Source-code:

1. MyViewModelTest.kt

   ```
   import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
   import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
   import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
   import com.pavneet_singh.temp.ui.main.testflow.*
   import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
   import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
   import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
   import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
   import org.junit.Before
   import org.junit.Rule
   import org.junit.Test
   import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor
   import org.mockito.Captor
   import org.mockito.Mock
   import org.mockito.Mockito.*
   import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

   class MyViewModelTest {

       @get:Rule
       val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

       @get:Rule
       val coroutineScope = MainCoroutineScopeRule()

       @Mock
       private lateinit var mockObserver: Observer<MyViewState>

       private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

       @Mock
       private lateinit var useCase: MyUseCase

       @Mock
       private lateinit var handle: SavedStateHandle

       @Mock
       private lateinit var chocolateList: List<ChocolateModel>

       private lateinit var viewState: MyViewState

       @Captor
       private lateinit var captor: ArgumentCaptor<MyViewState>


       @Before
       fun setup() {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
           viewState = MyViewState()
           myViewModel = MyViewModel(handle, useCase)
       }

       @Test
       fun onOptionsSelected() {
           runBlocking {
               val flow = flow {
                   emit(MyResult.Loading)
                   delay(10)
                   emit(MyResult.ChocolateList(chocolateList))
               }

               `when`(useCase.getListOfChocolates(MyAction.GetChocolateList)).thenReturn(flow)
               `when`(chocolateList.get(0)).thenReturn(ChocolateModel("Pavneet", 1))
               val liveData = myViewModel.onOptionsSelected()
               liveData.observeForever(mockObserver)

               verify(mockObserver).onChanged(captor.capture())
               assertEquals(true, captor.value.loading)
               coroutineScope.advanceTimeBy(10)
               verify(mockObserver, times(2)).onChanged(captor.capture())
               assertEquals("Pavneet", captor.value.data[0].name)// name is custom implementaiton field of `ChocolateModel` class
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. [MainCoroutineScopeRule.kt](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-codelab/finished_code/src/test/java/com/example/android/kotlincoroutines/main/utils/MainCoroutineScopeRule.kt) source to copy the file
3. List of `dependencies`

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
       implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
       implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
       implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
       implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0-alpha01'
       implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.16.0'
       testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
       testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.5'
       testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
   }
   ```

Output (gif is optimized by removing frames so bit laggy):

[image: Flow testing]

View [mvvm-flow-coroutine-testing](https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/mvvm-flow-coroutine-testing) repo on Github for complete implementaion.

Comment: How do we test LiveData this way?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky There are multiple ways, if you have a mocked or fake repository then you can trigger the events with desired data. or you could either use livedatabuilder or [flowasLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).asLiveData(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext,%20kotlin.Long)).

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh What if the received data is `PagingData<ModelName>`?

Comment: @Dr.jacky based on your implementation and flow, you probably will have to setup the mocked objects or faces.

Comment: What are the differences between 'src/test/' and 'src/androidTest' folders for unit testing the viewmodel class? how its handled the execution of viewmodel functions in a main thread?

Comment: the unit test should go under `src/test`, `src/androidTest` is for instrumentation tests. the execution depends on implementiaon and what/how you wanna test.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh how to achieve the same if we don't want to transform the `flow` into `liveData`. How to test the flow directly. I tried `flow.toList(destination)` but only receive the initial value of flow. Newly emitted events are not receives. Need your help.

Comment: @ankuranurag2 have you tried collecting the flow using `collect` or maybe use `.toList().last()`

Comment: I am facing something similar issue but in my case I need the flow in viewmodel update the screen with data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307504/android-espresso-kotlin-flow-not-collecting-data

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a better way to test this, by using Channel and `consumeAsFlow` extension function. At least in my tests, I seem to be able to test multiple values sent throught the channel (consumed as flow).

So.. say you have some use case component that exposes a `Flow<String>`. In your `ViewModelTest`, you want to check that everytime a value is emitted, the UI state gets updated to some value.
In my case, UI state is a `StateFlow`, but this should be do-able with LiveData as well.
Also, I am using MockK, but should also be easy with Mockito.

Given this, here is how my test looks:

```
@Test
fun test() = runBlocking(testDispatcher) {

    val channel = Channel<String>()
    every { mockedUseCase.someDataFlow } returns channel.consumeAsFlow()

    channel.send("a")
    assertThat(viewModelUnderTest.uiState.value, `is`("a"))

    channel.send("b")
    assertThat(viewModelUnderTest.uiState.value, `is`("b"))
}
```

EDIT: I guess you can also use any kind of *hot* flow implementation instead of `Channel` and `consumeAsFlow`. For example, you can use a `MutableSharedFlow` that enables you to `emit` values when you want.

Comment: May i know where that "every" comes from?

Comment: @wiryadev from the mockK library https://mockk.io/